# Case sensitive Order by for 2 first letters

Tags: c#, .net

I need a linq/lambda expression that sorts a list of strings but only the first 2 letters. Uppercase letters should be sorted first.

```
MyList.Sort((s1, s2) =>
    s1.Substring(0, 2).CompareTo(
    s2.Substring(0, 2)));
```

This is what i have now. It succesfully sorts the first 2 letters but when its case sensitive it fails...

EDIT: This is the result and works:

```
   var sorted = MyList.OrderBy(x =>x[0]).ThenBy(x => x[1]).ToList();
```

Comment: Notice it will fail if less than two characters in a string; you can use this one to compare https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06(v=vs.110).aspx with `StringComparison` you need

Comment: Yes. I can make it case sensitive but the problem is to both do that while only comparin first 2 letters

Comment: What do you mean by "when its case sensitive"? Do you want to sort it anyways?

Comment: If there is an input with "tree" and "Tree", Tree should be sorted first. Meaning upper cases sorting first

Comment: What if first two letters are similar? Should this sort be **stable**? If no, then you can simply sort your array, it guarantees that first two letters are sorted too.

Comment: yes it should be stable. If the first 2 letter are the same it should stay as they were input

Comment: OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal)

Comment: Tried this.. This takes the whole string into comparison. Only the first 2 letters should be used for sorting while its sorting upper case before lower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not a simple `OrderBy()` and `.ThenBy` as they performs a case sensitive comparison for sorting, consider the following code:

```
List<string> unOrderedList = new List<string>() { "bAC", "ABC", "aBc", "abc", "cAb", "Abx", "bbc", "bBx", "cAA" };
var orderedList = unOrderedList.OrderBy(x => x[0]).ThenBy(y=>y[1]).ToList();
```

Here in this case the `orderedList` will have the output as:

```
ABC
Abx
aBc
abc
bAC
bBx
bbc
cAb
cAA
```

See the example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1DuEi4), You can see that `Abx` have a higher position in the List than `aBc`, You can see a similar case in `bBx` and `bbc`.

Comment: @R.B : Cool Happy to help you

Comment: OrderBy use QuickSort internally, which is not a stable sort, so it may violate the condition specified by the OP once in while, which is about same order for same first two elements, a custom IComparer<string> would be a better choice, as that would make it certain